# Discrete inequality plotting

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have an equation like this: $${20 \choose k}\cdot \sum_{i=0}^k {k \choose i}\cdot i \leq 1+f$$.

I  want to plot this inequality as the dependency between `k` and `f`.
I found a commend `RegionPlot` but I don't know how to correctly use it in such equation.

Comment: You have an inequality, not an equation. `:)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Yes, you are right ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListPlot[Table[{k, Binomial[20, k] Sum[i Binomial[k, i] - 1, {i, 0, k}]}, {k, 1, 20}], Filling->Top]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or the same using a Log scale

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

If you want only integer values you can put `k` in `Round`:

```
RegionPlot[Binomial[20, Round[k]] Sum[
  i Binomial[Round[k], i], {i, 0, Round[k]}] <= 1 + f, {k, 1, 20}, {f, 0, 5 10^9}]
```

[image]

Your function is explicit, so it will be better to use `ListPlot` as in belisarius's answer:

```
ListPlot[Table[{k - 0.5, Binomial[20, k] Sum[i Binomial[k, i], {i, 0, k}] - 1}, {k, 20}], 
  Filling -> Top, Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

[image]

Also one can note that

```
Sum[i Binomial[k, i], {i, 0, k}]
```

> ```
>  2^(-1 + k) k
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The inequality you are considering is simplified as follow.

Consequently, we can use RegionPlot easily.

```
2^(-1+k) k Binomial[20,k]<=1+f
RegionPlot[2^(-1+k) k Binomial[20,k]<=1+f, {k,-4,10},{f,-20,40}]
```

[image]